# google map autocomplete field fetch address from database

Tags: google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I am running a script that has autocomplete field and fethes the address from google in the autocomplete firld.
I want to fetch the addresses in autocomplete field via database and then show the locations on map.

Here is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var mapOptions = {
   zoom: 10,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.890423,-79.417732)
     };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),mapOptions);

  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();  

 $(function() {
     $("#searchbox").autocomplete({

       source: function(request, response) {

      if (geocoder == null){
       geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      }
         geocoder.geocode( {'address': request.term }, function(results, status) {
           if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

              var searchLoc = results[0].geometry.location;
              var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
              var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
              var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
              var bounds = results[0].geometry.bounds;

              geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results1, status1) {
                  if (status1 == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    if (results1[1]) {
                     response($.map(results1, function(loc) {
                    return {
                        label  : loc.formatted_address,
                        value  : loc.formatted_address,
                        bounds   : loc.geometry.bounds
                      }
                    }));
                    }
                  }
                });
        }
          });
       },
       select: function(event,ui){
  var pos = ui.item.position;
  var lct = ui.item.locType;
  var bounds = ui.item.bounds;

  if (bounds){
   map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
       }
     });
 });   
 });
```

Any help is greately appreciated.
I am not much aware of google api and maps.

Comment: So instead of using the address from Geocode, you want to use addresses from your own database?

Comment: Use jquery-ui-autocomplete, places-autocomplete does not support custom data.